# Spring MVC add input box dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, spring-mvc

For JSP, I'm able to create one empty list and by default loading

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/npr.htm"})
public ModelAndView getHome(Model model) {
    ModelAndView viewModel = new ModelAndView();
    NPRBean nprBean = new NPRBean();
    try{
        //Initialize the first mobile number
        MobileNumber mb         = new MobileNumber();
        List mobilenumberlist   = new ArrayList<MobileNumber>();
        mobilenumberlist.add(0,mb);
        nprBean.setMobilenumberlist(mobilenumberlist);


        viewModel.addObject("nprBean",nprBean);
        viewModel.addObject("mobilenumberlist",mobilenumberlist);
        viewModel.setViewName("npr");
    }catch (Exception e){
        logger.error("Error ::" + e);
    }
    return viewModel;
}
```

For jsp :

```
<c:set var="count" value="0" scope="page" />
    <c:forEach items="${nprBean.mobilenumberlist}" var="mobilelst" varStatus="loopStatus">
                            <div>
                                <label>Mobile Number ${count+1}</label>
                                <spring:bind path="nprBean.mobilenumberlist[${loopStatus.index }].phonenumberheader">
                                <
                                <select name="<c:out value="${status.expression}"/>" id="phonenumberheader-${count}" class="style12">
                                  <option value="">Please Select</option>
                                  <c:forEach items="${nprBean.mobilenumberheaderlist}" var="lst">
                                  <option value="<c:out value="${lst.numberHeader}"/>" 
                                        <c:if test="${mobilelst.phonenumberheader == lst.numberHeader}"> selected="selected"</c:if>>
                                        <c:out value="${lst.numberHeader}"/>
                                  </option>
                                  </c:forEach>
                                </select>
                                </spring:bind>
                                  -
                                <spring:bind path="nprBean.mobilenumberlist[${loopStatus.index }].phonenumber">
                                <input name="<c:out value="${status.expression}"/>" id="phonenumber-${count}" value="<c:out value="${mobilelst.phonenumber}"/>" class="style12" type="text" size="8" maxlength="9" onKeyPress="return ValidateKeyPress(event,3);" onblur="convertToCaps(this);trimSpace(this);"/></td>
                                </spring:bind>

                             </div>
    <c:set var="count" value="${count + 1}" scope="page"/>  
    </c:forEach>
```

But now I'm trying to increase the mobilenumberlist by clicking add button, and fire an ajax to controller and add the size of the list, which is like :

```
$('#addnum').on('click', function(e) {
    $.ajax("npr/npraddrow.json?" + $('#search-form').serialize(), {
        method: "GET",
        accepts: "application/json",
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function(data) {
        console.log("result ::"+data.result);


    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            var errorMessage = "";
            if (jqXHR.status == 401) {
                errorMessage = "Your session has expired. Please <a href=\"<spring:url value='/login'/>\">login</a> again.";
            } else {
            try {
                var errorJson = JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText);
                errorMessage = errorJson.error;
            } catch (e) {
                errorMessage = errorThrown || textStatus;
            }
            }
        });
    return true;
});
```

<strike>The question here is, how can i replace the existing JSTL value ?
and how can I get all the value in the list back to controller?</strike>

**update scenario with screen[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oJ8D.png)**

I need to add row of input text box dynamically upon click on add button, anyway to do this ?

Comment: What do you mean by _how can i replace the existing jstl value?_ Serialize the list and sent it back to the controller via ajax post.

Comment: @Lucky im able to get the object from controller, but i do not know how to replace the object value inside the list, 
and the list value is populated by jstl earlier.

Comment: You don't deal with JSTL in your browser. You should be having HTML content in your webpage. You need to form html content and and replace/append it with existing HTML displayed in your page using javascript. Also, post your `npr/npraddrow.json` controller action method.

Comment: @Lucky then i think my approach is totally wrong, my scenario should be when i click add button, i need to increase the size of the list, thus in jsp there is a new row of item will be shown